# using generics correctly with maps

Tags: java, generics

i have all sorts of items extending baseItem.
for each type i have a special handler class.

i use a map of handlers, using the item className.
so my handling method is something like this:

```
private boolean handle(BaseItem item) {

    BaseItemHandler bih = mapOfHandlers.get(item.getClass().getSimpleName());
    return bih.handleItem(item);

}
```

and the map is of type:

```
map<string,BaseItemHandler> mapOfHandlers;
```

but i'm (obviously) getting a "Unchecked call" warning.
what is the *correct* way of doing

***EDIT:***
the items are

```
public interface BaseItem{}
```

and the BaseItemHandler is:

```
public interface BaseItemHandler<T extends BaseItem> {

    public boolean handleItem(T item);
}
```

Comment: I'd bet money the answer is "you can't do this typesafely" because it pretty much always is.

Comment: Could you use a _HandlerFactory_ or add a method to each BaseItem that returns an appropriate _Handler_ (rather than using a Map)?

Comment: Please enlighten me, where did you get this warning? I copied the code and added several classes needed for compilation but cannot find the warning you posted.

Comment: @ZiyaoWei did you create an `abstract Class BaseItemHandler` with a method `abstract boolean Handle(BaseItem item);` ?

Comment: Yes, I just changed i to that. Could you post exactly where the warning is from, maybe separate the code into several lines to somewhat isolate the warning inducing code?

Comment: A complete example, with class signatures for `BaseItem` and `BaseItemHandler`, would help.

Comment: `map<string,BaseItemHandler> mapOfHandlers;` - that's really careless, you should fix that. Is `BaseItemHandler` generic? Is `handleItem` method generic? You haven't posted enough information. If you are not sure whats generating the warning, break down the line `mapOfHandlers.get(item.getClass().getSimpleName()).handleItem(item)`.

Comment: p.s. your `handle` method should just be declared as `private boolean handle(BaseItem item)`

Answer (score 4):

java.util.Map does not permit expressing a type constraint between an individual key and its value, and even if it did, generics are too weak to make use of that constraint in Map.get(), as the implementation of Map.get() can not convince the compiler that the type parameter of its argument is identical to the type parameter of the map entry being accessed. Any such implementation will therefore require a cast.

You can use a checked cast, though:

```
abstract class Handler<I extends BaseItem> {
    final Class<I> iClass;
    protected Handler(Class<I> iClass) {
        this.iClass = iClass;
    }

    void handle(BaseItem i) {
        doHandle(iClass.cast(i));
    }

    abstract void doHandle(I i);
}
```

However, this introduces a method with an overly permissive signature, and callers might accidentally use that signature elsewhere in the program, needlessly bypassing compile time type checking. An unchecked cast seems a lesser price to pay.

If you are concerned about the possiblity of heap pollution, I'd check the type of the handler during registration:

```
class HandlerMap {
    Map<Class<?>, Handler<?>> map = new HashMap<>();

    public void register(Handler<?> h) {
        map.put(h.iClass, h);
    }

    public <I extends BaseItem> Handler<I> get(I i) {
        return (Handler<I>) map.get(i.getClass());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This method does not need to be generic, try this

```
private boolean handle(BaseItem item) {
    return mapOfHandlers.get(item.getClass().getSimpleName()).handleItem(item);
}
```

Comment: still the same. it doesn't really matter the method is generic. the thing is BaseItemHandler.handle(BaseItem). i thought it could be solved with generics.